# vuejs nested slots with props don't get down

Tags: vuejs2, nested, slots, vue-props

I want to push down a prop "multi" from vDropdownSelection to "vOptions". How can I do that without adding ":multi" on each option? I tried slotprops but it doesn't work...

This is my setup.

```html
<!-- root -->
  <vDropdownSelection :multi="true">
    <vOption id="dd5" label="Choose me" />
    <vOption id="dd6" label="No take me" />
    <vOption id="dd7" label="I don't care..."/>
  </vDropdownSelection>
```

multi gets true

```js
//vDropdownSelection
<template>
  <vPopOver>
    <template #trigger="{ click }"> 
      <button @click.prevent="click">{{ label }}</button>
    </template >
    <template #default>
      <vSelectGroup :multi="multi" #default="{multi}">
        {{ multi }} // shows true
        <slot :multi="multi"/> // cannot pass multi ´
      </vSelectGroup>
    </template>
  </vPopOver>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    multi: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

multi gets true

```js
//vSelectGroup
<template>
  <div>
     <slot :multi="multi"/>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    multi: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

multi stays false...

```js
// options
<template>
  <div>
    <input :type="isType">
    <label>{{ label }}</label>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    multi: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    }
  },  
  computed: {
    isType() {
      return this.multi ? 'checkbox' : 'radio'
    }
  }
}
</script>
```